# Android SDK Error Upon Creating Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am running into a problem creating an android emulator from the command line.  When I run the android command the messages below output.

> Starting Android SDK and AVD Manager
>
> SWT folder 'lib\x86_64' does not exist
>
> Please set ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for platform

I've already:

1. Execute SDK Setup.exe and brought down the android packages
2. Modified my environment variables to point to the tools folder
3. Verified that the SWT.jar was in fact located in lib\x86_64

I've already successfully set this up on my primary development unit.  The system I am installing on now runs 64-bit Windows 7 (same as my other development unit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same error message show up when I was trying to get Android up and running. However after looking around online I found a command which fixed my problem.

Try running this from the command line:

`android create avd --target 2 --name my_avd`